# Login to Sharepoint via 3rd party IDP via ADFS and ADFS Trusted Claims Provider?

Tags: sharepoint, adfs

I have set up some trusted claims providers (SAML 2.0) within ADFS and when I access the ADFS login screen these options are displayed and login via these 3rd party IDPs works correctly.

I have also setup Sharepoint as a trusted relying party with ADFS and when I access the sharepoint site I can select my trusted provider and am redirected to the ADFS login screen.  However this screen only has the username/password form and not the options for the trusted claims providers in the above flow.

Does Sharepoint support auth federated through ADFS to a trusted claims provider?

Comment: Did you try to log in? What interface do you enter after logging in? Will logging in via the username/password form be redirected to an interface that authenticates the user?

Comment: Removing Active Directory as the ClaimsProviderName for the relying party trust provider fixed the issue

Comment: Next problem is getting Sharepoint to accept the ADFS Token when logging into Sharepoint via Choose Trusted Provider->ADFS->Trusted Claims Provider .

 I get this error:  An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm..

If logging in via Sharepoint via Choose Trusted Provider->ADFS->Active Directory it works f